# Google reward video failed to load

Tags: android, admob

I am using admob reward video in my application. But  every time I get the below logs and video gets failed to load. I am not using any Mediation network. I tried deleting my adunit and created a new one but it worked for 1 time and stopped working after that. I have a banner view also for the same project and it works fine.

I tried using the test device as well in my code but that didn't helped either

I tried downloading the google sample app for reward video and replaced my appid and adunit id and that's also not working. I even tried changin g my package name but all in vain

```
04-27 13:05:48.838 27993-27993/com.phomotech.dicegame I/Ads: Updating ad debug logging enablement.
04-27 13:05:48.880 27993-27993/com.phomotech.dicegame I/Ads: Starting ad request.
04-27 13:05:48.882 27993-27993/com.phomotech.dicegame I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B445576D53CC2D3C563D556644F72240") to get test ads on this device.
04-27 13:05:48.908 27993-27993/com.phomotech.dicegame D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
04-27 13:05:48.917 27993-27993/com.phomotech.dicegame I/Ads: Updating ad debug logging enablement.
04-27 13:05:48.921 27993-27993/com.phomotech.dicegame I/Ads: Starting ad request.
04-27 13:05:48.922 27993-27993/com.phomotech.dicegame I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B445576D53CC2D3C563D556644F72240") to get test ads on this device.
04-27 13:05:48.953 27993-29240/com.phomotech.dicegame W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
04-27 13:05:48.953 27993-29213/com.phomotech.dicegame W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
04-27 13:05:49.691 27993-28016/com.phomotech.dicegame I/Ads: No fill from ad server.
04-27 13:05:49.819 27993-27993/com.phomotech.dicegame W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
04-27 13:05:50.096 27993-27993/com.phomotech.dicegame I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 70000 milliseconds from now.
04-27 13:05:50.133 27993-27993/com.phomotech.dicegame I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
```

Answer (score 1):

> W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3

As per the Documentation you are getting the following error code:

> public static final int ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL
>
> The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.
>
> Constant Value: 3

Based on the post onFailedToReceiveAd - Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory when using admob with:

> If you are getting this error, then your code is correct. The issue is
>   that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request.
>   This may happen particularly if you have just registered your AdMob
>   publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before the
>   new ID starts returning ads.
>
> Another reason your fill rate may be low is that you don't have AdSense backfill enabled, or you have filtered out some ads. Check
>   your app settings to see if that is the case.

Copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712905/1427445

Comment: I have seen this answer earlier. Its been 2 days I have created my ad unit id.

Comment: hi @MRX, I've faced that problem, because admob lack of ad inventory. Dont worry about that. The ads can show if user is on other location or is the same with the ads target.