# Admob Banner Ads are not appearing after publishing my application

Tags: android, admob, ads

I published my Application few days ago in Play Store, everything works perfectly, the Ads (Banner & Interstitial) were appearing as expected. But today, i discovered that the Interstitial Ads are appearing but not Banner ads. This is my first application and I don't know what may be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes ads are not shown due to lack of ads in google's ad inventory. You can check ad request response code to be sure.

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {
    // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
}

@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    Log.d("ADMOB_ERROR_CODE", "admob error code: " + errorCode);
}

@Override
public void onAdOpened() {
    // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
    // covers the screen.
}

@Override
public void onAdLeftApplication() {
    // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
}

@Override
public void onAdClosed() {
    // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
    // to the app after tapping on an ad.
}
});
```

Further Reading: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Comment: Shall I contact Admob? or just wait for this problem to be resolved?

Comment: Here is the result of this code: D/ADMOB_ERROR_CODE: admob error code: 3

Comment: As I guessed. The error code means lack of inventory.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712905/2797847 . When there are sufficient ads, the adview will show ads correctly. Just handle this case.

Comment: This wont take a lot of time? because my revenue for today are 0.00 !

Comment: It might take time. Sometimes it is device specific, it may show on mobiles but not on tablets.

Comment: thanx a lot for your help.

Comment: @minhazur Ad not refresh after get error 3. Again Ad loaded only called loadAd(). Have any idea?

Comment: @Sakthi If I understand you correctly, Admob ads can be unpredictable for some countries or regions based on ad inventory and their algorithm.

Comment: @minhazur Thanks for ur response. I'm using DFP Banner(PublisherAdView) Ad, once failed not auto refreshed for next cycle. For my doubt if need to reload again? or automatically refreshed again.

Comment: @minhazur Another one doubt, try for DFP mediation with FAN. I can't see FB ad using mediation. Instead-of directly i call FB ad means it can be visible. Guide me?

Comment: @Sakthi Sorry, I can't help you with that as I haven't work on FAN.

Comment: @minhazur Ok, I'm using DFP Banner(PublisherAdView) Ad, once loaded ad it will be auto refreshed every minute. But once failed not auto refreshed for next cycle. For my doubt if need to reload again? or automatically refreshed again. Thanks in advance.