# Android studio admob rewarded video failed to load ad : 3

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

Hi I'm having a problem with admob's rewarded video ad, I've search everywhere and nothing seems to fix the failed to load ad error.
i tried to add aplovin in the mediation , load the add from different app in admob (which has working ads - banner and interstitial), and I have been waiting for about a week , as most of the answers was to wait if the add is new.
nothing seems to work and I'm clueless right now.

As I already mentioned , other ads are working and only the rewarded video ad doesn't work' also the test ad of the rewarded video is working.

Comment: Does you getting the error code 3 on ad load right?

Comment: Yes I get that when I'm loading the ad

Comment: Than it is a error code for the no fill because the google admob doesn't have that kind of ad at a time that's why.
Here is the reference link for more detail :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712905/6096821

Comment: I know this is the reson but as I already mentioned, I waited a week, so it is not a matter of time, something else is causing the error.

Comment: Have you added any minimum eCPM price?

Comment: I don't think so, doesn't it being added automaticly?

Comment: No. We have to set it manually. If we want.