# 3 Admobs apps, 1 of which keeps failing on load with error code 3

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have 3 Android apps, only 2 currently in store.
Each of them is on a seperate mediation group but all have exactly the same settings and the same ad unit types.

Basically, They're all the same and should work the same but one of them DO NOT.

One of the apps keeps failing on loading the ad with errorcode 3, I noticed that If I keep the app running then after a while it manages to load successfully.
I'm not doing anything differently code-wise, all apps work the same way, so what can possibly cause this?

I know what the error means by the way, I checked online before and I have no clue why this one is different.

Comment: Have you checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)? Actually, there is no problem in your code but your ad inventory is not returning any ad.

Comment: @VirajPatel I already know there's no problem in my code, I also read bout what error 3 means. Thing is, It's the same code in all 3 apps but only 1 fail like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2993019?hl=en) it's not your fault.

I have same problem and it's solution is increase you app user so send ad request to admob and show your ad.

It's rule is latest rule and admob privacy make strong so apply this rule

Before 2017 it's rule is not so ad show is work fine, but right now first to send some ad request than ad show

I hope solve your question.

When apps are newly registered with AdMob, it takes some time and a few ad requests to allow inventory to build. Because of this, you may not see live impressions immediately.