# admob Ad failed to load : 3

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am developing an android app , I want to show banner ads in my app .My previous apps works correctly and the ads are shown . When I create my new app ads did not show even in the old apps

it shows ads failed to load ad:3

this what is shown in the logcat

```
11-29 18:52:54.831: D/ViewRootImpl(31298): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
11-29 18:52:54.921: D/ViewRootImpl(31298): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
11-29 18:52:54.921: I/Timeline(31298): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:apps.s.r.sh time:126574535
11-29 18:52:54.951: W/ResourcesManager(31298): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/apps.s.r.sh-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in apps.s.r.sh rsrc of package null
11-29 18:52:54.951: W/ResourcesManager(31298): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/apps.s.r.sh-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in apps.s.r.sh rsrc of package null
11-29 18:52:55.241: D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(31298): Metadata value : none
11-29 18:52:55.251: D/ViewRootImpl(31298): #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b1e1489 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
11-29 18:52:55.571: W/DisplayListCanvas(31298): DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
11-29 18:52:55.591: D/ViewRootImpl(31298): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
11-29 18:52:55.851: I/Timeline(31298): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1308390 time:126575466
11-29 18:52:55.861: V/ActivityThread(31298): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{c3eecaf token=android.os.BinderProxy@2057663 {apps.s.r.sh/apps.s.r.sh.MainActivity}} show : false
11-29 18:52:56.921: D/ViewRootImpl(31298): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
11-29 18:52:56.991: D/ViewRootImpl(31298): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
11-29 18:52:57.001: I/Timeline(31298): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:apps.s.r.sh time:126576611
11-29 18:52:57.031: W/ResourcesManager(31298): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/apps.s.r.sh-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in apps.s.r.sh rsrc of package null
11-29 18:52:57.031: W/ResourcesManager(31298): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/apps.s.r.sh-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in apps.s.r.sh rsrc of package null
11-29 18:52:57.081: W/ResourcesManager(31298): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in apps.s.r.sh rsrc of package null
11-29 18:52:57.261: W/DynamiteModule(31298): Failed to load module via V2: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/apps.s.r.sh-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/apps.s.r.sh-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-29 18:52:57.271: I/DynamiteModule(31298): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:10900
11-29 18:52:57.271: I/DynamiteModule(31298): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 10900
11-29 18:52:57.311: W/ResourcesManager(31298): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in apps.s.r.sh rsrc of package null
11-29 18:52:57.371: W/System(31298): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000094/n/armeabi-v7a
11-29 18:52:57.371: W/System(31298): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000094/n/armeabi
11-29 18:52:57.381: W/ResourcesManager(31298): getTopLevelResources: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000094/AdsDynamite.apk / 1.0 running in apps.s.r.sh rsrc of package null
11-29 18:52:57.391: W/ResourcesManager(31298): getTopLevelResources: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000094/AdsDynamite.apk / 1.0 running in apps.s.r.sh rsrc of package null
11-29 18:52:57.391: D/DynamitePackage(31298): Instantiated singleton DynamitePackage.
11-29 18:52:57.391: D/DynamitePackage(31298): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
11-29 18:52:57.531: I/Ads(31298): Updating ad debug logging enablement.
11-29 18:52:57.541: I/Ads(31298): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("5165705B1A22CACD4E59EB67DC3FCE56") to get test ads on this device.
11-29 18:52:57.621: W/Ads(31298): Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
11-29 18:52:57.621: W/Ads(31298): The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
11-29 18:52:57.631: W/DynamiteModule(31298): Failed to load module via V2: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/apps.s.r.sh-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/apps.s.r.sh-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-29 18:52:57.641: I/DynamiteModule(31298): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:10900
11-29 18:52:57.641: I/DynamiteModule(31298): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 10900
11-29 18:52:57.641: I/WebViewFactory(31298): Loading com.google.android.webview version 70.0.3538.110 (code 353811000)
11-29 18:52:57.661: W/ResourcesManager(31298): getTopLevelResources: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000094/AdsDynamite.apk / 1.0 running in apps.s.r.sh rsrc of package null
11-29 18:52:57.661: D/SecWifiDisplayUtil(31298): Metadata value : none
11-29 18:52:57.661: D/ViewRootImpl(31298): #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4488dba I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
11-29 18:52:57.681: W/Ads(31298): Update ad debug logging enablement as false
11-29 18:52:57.751: W/ResourcesManager(31298): getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in apps.s.r.sh rsrc of package null
11-29 18:52:57.761: D/ViewRootImpl(31298): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
11-29 18:52:57.771: W/DisplayListCanvas(31298): DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
11-29 18:52:57.791: I/Timeline(31298): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e9b4ee5 time:126577403
11-29 18:52:57.901: I/art(31298): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<hs>
11-29 18:52:57.901: I/art(31298): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<hs>
11-29 18:52:57.921: V/ActivityThread(31298): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{47d0972 token=android.os.BinderProxy@1308390 {apps.s.r.sh/apps.s.r.sh.First}} show : false
11-29 18:52:57.921: I/cr_LibraryLoader(31298): Time to load native libraries: ? ms (timestamps ????-????)
11-29 18:52:57.991: I/chromium(31298): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
11-29 18:52:57.991: I/cr_LibraryLoader(31298): Expected native library version number "70.0.3538.110", actual native library version number "70.0.3538.110"
11-29 18:52:58.821: I/Ads(31298): Ad failed to load : 3
```

The app is workimg but the ads is not showing!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wait 3-5 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

> It simply says that your code is correct. The issue is that AdMob does
>   not always have an ad to return for every request. This may happen
>   particularly if you have just registered your AdMob publisher ID, as
>   it takes some time and multiple requests before the new ID starts
>   returning ads.

Wait for some time may be you have just created you ad id's, but if this is not the case 
then try changing app package name i.e application ID

**How to Change Android App Package Name?**

1. To change Package name of an android app, go to the Project window,
   right click on the app, then select Open Module Settings,
2. A new window will appear, select the Flavours tab in the window.
   this is where we will change the app package name i.e **application
   id**  renaming it to anything just follow the syntax

[image]

Comment: I registered in admob before few months , I try the second way which is changing the package name and it worked :) the problem is that I already publish my app in google play and this version is an update so I have to use the same package name

Comment: when I try to run the app again it did not show the ads even when changing the package name !!

Comment: @ShRS you can then contact to admob support team tell them that you are facing this issue because this can only happen if they have excluded your AdMob account from serving ads? Your other ad id's are they working? If yes try using some existing and working ad id

Comment: my other ads in the other apps are working fine .How I can contact admob support team?

Comment: login to your AdMob account and from left side menu click on Help Then a window will pop up on right bottom choose new customer help, then just follow on screen instruction

Comment: my module window appears empty

Answer (score 0):

Actually i couldnt understand the solution, if you change the package name in code, you should also change the app in play console because google wants all the releases might have same package name. Did you create new app in console? @Sh R S

Comment: No I did not create new app . I changed the packege name to other name .Then I test the app and the adds was working .After that I change it to the same name as before because I want to publish it as an update.When I test the app in the end the ads works. @user3021030

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this **error code 3**, then your code is correct. The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request. ... Another reason your fill rate may be low is that you don't have AdSense backfill enabled, or you have filtered out some ads. Check your app settings to see if that is the case

Answer (score -1):

My problem was solved by changing the package name by:

1- right click in the project

2- android tools

3- rename application package

check the manifest to make sure that the package name was changed

then :

project---> clean