# Unable to load ads

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

[my logcat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYGhA.png)
Am getting below errors for my applications not able to see ads on the application
but the test ads are displaying could you please help

> W/Ads: App does not have the required permissions to get location
>    I/Ads: SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v14574020.10084000.1
>    I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3

Answer (score 0):

Your app has no permissions to access location. So you either has not specified it in manifest file or by default this permission is not granted. Check the app permissions in settings. You can check permissions programmatically. I think test ads does not require location and that is why they are being displayed while actual ads are not.

Comment: thank you for your immediate answer.is it the problem with permission that im unable to load ads.im not understanding why ads are not showing.i have attached my logcat image have a look and please help me

Comment: Since test ads are loading properly I think the problem is in permissions, please take a look at app settings in your phone and check if permission is granted

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add permission for location in the manifest as far as Admob is concerned.

> The ad failed to load : 3 is because of the issue from Google server end, Ads are still not served to your app from Google end

refer to this [admob Ad failed to load : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542030/admob-ad-failed-to-load-3/53543103?noredirect=1#comment94013249_53543103) for more help I have answered the same question 
If you think your code is correct and your other apps are showing ads contact the Admob Support team

Comment: I have 4 apps in playstore.when I install them from playstore they are showing ads but when I run the same apps from computer ads are not showing.in logcat above mentioned errors are showing for all the apps.i don't understand whether it is problem from my side or admob server side.please help me

Comment: This is clearly not a problem from your side. I do have a similar problem in two of my apps, try contacting Admob support team from your Admob console.

Comment: How to contact admob support team

Comment: login to your AdMob account and from left side menu click on Help Then a window will pop up on right bottom choose new customer help, then just follow on screen instruction

Comment: There is no new customer help option in popup window

Comment: There will be an option similar to this new Customer support or something like this or post a snap shop of pop up window

Comment: Hi Rajat 
there is no way to contact from new customer support could you please guide me how to contact them. i observed  in help forums many are facing the issue  from nov 29  .Did you also face the same issue from nov29 ? as per some peoples comments review is being going from Admob not sure if its correct 
did your problem resolved if so how?
please help

Comment: No I am still not receiving ad on one of my app neither in debug mode not in Release mode