# Admob test ads are ok, but real ads don't displaying

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have a android app in the market.

Even if I can see the both test and real ads in debug mode while I am working on Android studio, there is no real ads in release code in market.

I also tried to add test ids and look at what is going on, test ads come.

I guess I cannot see the real ads only.

```
My App Id: ca-app-pub-3563728244453785~8287872800
Logcat is also checked, returns:
I/Ads: Use 
AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("C17538FC9133629C3B64CF1B85F65481")
```

to get test ads on this device.

```
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
```

Is there anyone can help me for this?

Comment: You can find your answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

Comment: I also checked these comments but code is on market in almost in a week. I checked my app settings all of them is OK. I ve another app, and ads are still working on, so i am not banned i guess. Test ids are working, i checked the ads button in play console also.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with me.

Your code is right. Every thing is right.

Just make live the application with real ids, it will be visible in live build.