# admob Ad failed to load : 3?

Tags: android, admob

i am using admob from one year and every month i am updating my apps to newer version but from past 2 weeks ads not showing in most of the devices, like only 10 devices showing ads out of 100 devices(only for first time) and i tested like

1. testing in emulator with testing id and my admob id both are working fine,
2. i tested using VPN with some other countries ips ads working with every devices ( but for example some particular countries like indian ip not showing, here is the main issues)
3. and when deply to app store 1k impression per 10k page views and im pretty sure im not violating any polices
4. and error code admob Ad failed to load : 3
5. `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'`
6. `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`
7. i dont know whats happing this type of error from google server errors or my apps?? any help

Comment: is this issues with my apps or my account? what a funny admob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

Comment: I know possible duplicate but see the situation only few devices are showing ads

Comment: i had the same problem when i updated my app to newer version com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0

Answer (score 0):

From google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL)

> public static final int ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL
>
> The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.
>
> Constant Value: 3

That means, you ad request was successful but google server didn't provide any ads due to lack of ads.

Which means, **you did your part**, google might or might not provide ads when they think any ads worthy of showing to that particular user or not.