# AdMob live ads doesn't show up

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to integrate AdMob ads to my android app.When I use test mode(defining my device as test device with device id) ads loads perfectly. But when I exit test mode ads doesn't show up.

This is the error i get:

```
"Ad failed to load : 3"
```

I searched what this error means. And I found out there is no add to load. Peoples telling me if my account is new I have to wait 1 day to show up the ads. But I created my AdMob account 14 days ago. So far I have worked with test ads only and now I can't load live ads.

Some people suggested me yo set up payment methods for getting live ads. But, AdMob doesnt let me to set up my payment method because I havent earned any money yet.

[failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485)

This question and my question is not same question. Because that questions answer says if you have just created you account its normal to not having ads but i created my admob account 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

Answer (score 0):

The same situation was with me a week ago. Did you received email a message like that?
[image]

If not, check your account, fill all the information about you.

Comment: İ just want to know do i have to publish my app on play store to see real ads.because my app is still in development phase.

Comment: Sure, try to change your build variant to release, and check.

Comment: How to do that. Do you want me to build a signed apk?

Comment: No, in the left side of Android Studio, there is "Build Variant". Inside you can change debug vs release.

Comment: Also here is an more detailed answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I tried signed release apk but still same no ads showing

Comment: Maybe you chose a high rate of ecpm? Check your unit ad id, app id.

Comment: My app id and ad unit id is correct and my ecpm filter is disabled but still no ads