# Reward video ad can't be loaded with content_rating extra

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I'm trying to show reward video ad in my android game with google admob. There is no problem in loading and showing reward ad if I don't put any content_rating parameter as Bundle extras. But when I put "max_ad_content_rating" with "T" logcat say "I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3". What the problem is? I'm using test ad unit id. May be it seem to be duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3). But it is a little different.
In my case, the ad can be loaded successfully and not return error code 3, but I put "max_ad_content_rating" parameter the problem arise.

Comment: Have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3 and **[this links](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Ads%3A+Ad+failed+to+load+%3A+3&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)