# why does Ad Mob Not showing ads in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, admob

I am trying to implement ads from AdMob in Flutter app. I created Admob Id two days ago and my account has approved by AdMob.I tested the app(Banner Ad) by test App ID and its working but it's not working with my real APP ID  .

looking for help

```
I/Ads     (14486): No fill from ad server.
W/Ads     (14486): Failed to load ad: 3
I/flutter (14486): Admob banner failed to load. Error code: 3
```

Comment: conside posting your code and enclose errors and code in codeblock

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

Answer (score 3):

try build an apk of your app and then install it manually on your device.

Answer (score 2):

Does the test ID work normally? then... maybe it's not your fault. AdMob has some problem since a few months ago. reference below links. Many people are having the same problem. (Even AdMob seems to think they have a problem.)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/rTfuhBjGkpc

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-help-forum/8oc3pebOrFw/EicKPpUVDgAJ

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do Flutter. If you are getting Error code: 3, you are doing nothing wrong. Sometimes AdMob does not fill your ad request on some regions if currently there is no matching ad for your request. You can check out matching rate in AdMob site. What you can do to solve this issue is using mediation or changing number of providers or the current providers you enabled on GDPR screen of AdMob.