# Interstitial Failed to load should i keep asking or?

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I have a more of a tactics question
In my app i often get failed to load ad error code 3
My app is not banned , my admob account is fine i know that this error means that google has no ads to offer BUT 
My question is what should i do after i get this error

1) Should i keep asking for ad with the code below? If i keep asking i finaly get an ad but shouldnt this will lead to app ban?

```
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
```

2) Should i mediate with other networks?

3) Should i do nothing of the above and let my app mature and get more ads from google ?

4) is it true that according to the audience and app oldines google is providing more ads?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Answer is in here [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712905/2925157)

Comment: yeap you really didnt answer any of the above 4 questions though..

Answer (score 1):

If you read mentioned post, you can see answers. [Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3/33712905#33712905)

**A1:**

> If you are getting this error, then your code is correct. The issue is
>   that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request.

**A2:**

> Another reason your fill rate may be low is that you don't have
>   AdSense backfill enabled, or you have filtered out some ads. Check
>   your app settings to see if that is the case.

**A3:**
Questions 3 and 4 same. This is not about oldines or maturity.