# Not retrying to fetch app settings: admob

Tags: android, admob

I have a game on playstore, I implemented rewarded video ads and my ads have been serving very well with a match rate of 100% in fact. But all of a sudden ads refuse to load with a match rate < 1% for the past three days. I test it on android studio. I get this error:

```
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
```

EDIT:
The other question does not contain this error:

```
W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
```

I've never seen this before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

Comment: [Plese refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3) Hope this helps! Thank You

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue with test ads (I don't like testing with real ads as admob is quick to impose ad limits), If you are using test ads to test on a app which is also published on playstore with same package name and you have also set up an app-ads.txt file for your app, Admob test ads will not work

here is what Admob says: If you set up an app-ads.txt file for your app, you need to also include this line in your app-ads.txt file in order to load ads using the demo ad units:
google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0

Alternatively, you can enable test devices and use your own ad unit IDs instead.
read it here : https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Comment: You may need to wait for 24 hrs after adding app-ads.txt entry.

Answer (score 3):

W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3

As per the Documentation, you are getting the following error code:

public static final int ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to a lack of ad inventory.

Constant Value: 3

Based on the post onFailedToReceiveAd - Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory when using AdMob with adwhirl:

If you are getting this error, then your code is correct. The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request. This may happen particularly if you have just registered your AdMob Publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before the new ID starts returning ads.

Another reason your fill rate may below is that you don't have AdSense backfill enabled, or you have filtered out some ads. Check your app settings to see if that is the case.