# not showing ads in release mode

Tags: android, admob, release

Not showing admob in release mode.
But in test mode, it works normally.
Release mode prompts you to add a test device.

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                //.addTestDevice("42DACEF759D862A1F97B643B83982FB6") //This line has been commented out.
                .build();

        adFull = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        adFull.setAdUnitId("UnitId");
        adFull.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Logcat message>>

```
2019-03-26 12:16:40.969 8865-8865/? I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("42DACEF759D862A1F97B643B83982FB6") to get test ads on this device.
2019-03-26 12:16:41.340 5349-9213/? W/Ads: App does not have the required permissions to get location
2019-03-26 12:16:41.524 5349-10814/? I/Ads: SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v15090019.15000000.1
2019-03-26 12:16:42.113 8865-8865/? I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
```

Comment: `adFull.show()` add this

Comment: @KishanViramgama  
adFull.setAdListener(new AdListener() { 
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                adFull.show();
            }

Comment: check with ad-mob test id. real id some time work after uploading in play store app and check this link error code 3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3

Comment: i checked test id. it is no problem.

Comment: real id some time work after uploading in play store app and You Have To Add Payment Details in Admob Account.

Comment: I know. It's been a day since I uploaded it to the Play Store.

Comment: great and share your application link with me if it possible