# Error Admob: onAdFailedToLoad Error code 3

Tags: android, admob

I am working on AdMob but I am getting **error code 3**. I know there are lots of question regarding the same. But I tried everything nothing works. I have also followed this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712905/2196176) But nothing works for me.
Somebodies said adsense is not properly configured. Here is the screenshot of my account setting.[image]

If I am using **addTestDevice** its working fine.

I read somewhere I need to wait for a few hours and after that, it starts working. But it's almost one month, nothing happened. Strange thing is that with the same account on iOS it working fine. I am facing issue only Android Side.

I hope anybody faced the same and can help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving testing ads, but not real ads, then your implementation for ads is all okay.

AdMob is very poor in providing ads. So I suggest you to add other ads networks too if one of network is failed to provide ads.(E.g. Facebook, StartApp, AppLovin etc.)

Comment: Thanks!! But adding the other networks depend on the client. But how the same working fine on iOS, any idea?