# Ads were fine untill yesterday admob error code 3 is being triggered

Tags: android, admob

My app ads were working fine, untill today, it has started showing error code 3. Without any change to the code or ids.

Comment: Post your logcat please

Comment: where does it show it? How does it look?

Comment: answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3 your question is duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

Comment: @RubenMeiring I dont have one as i had this app running and showing ads after i built a release, it just stopped giving ads and i previously put a check for Error code 3 and now its triggering the check in my app

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I made a check for error code 3 to display a toast if the Error code 3 is triggered and its going into that and popping up the same toast, Also the ads were working fine until yesterday

Comment: @ДмитрийГаврилов The question is irrelevent as the person who asked never loaded any ads ever, My app was working fine and giving ads until yesterday and now its giving a no fill

Comment: the accepted answer 100% answers your question. Please read it first.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the question says request is made, I have error code 3 and still my admob says i have 0 requests

Comment: ok, then `where does it show it? How does it look? `

Comment: **where** it shows it, and **how**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to Invalid Traffic.