# Admob Error - onAdFailedToLoad error code 3

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I try create admob banner in my app and I get error code 3
please help me to get solution.

I have meta-data in manifest

layout:

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView111"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9038559490997069/7964491403">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9038559490997069/7964491403");
    adView = findViewById(R.id.adView111);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            Log.e("onAdLoaded","AdLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            Log.e("onAdFailedToLoad",""+errorCode);

        }
    });

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

I know have error 3 if admob account is new,
I create my admob account before one week.

i get some Logs:

```
W/FA-Ads: Disabling data collection. Found google_app_id in strings.xml but Google Analytics for Firebase is missing. Remove this value or add Google Analytics for Firebase to resume data collection.2019-12-13 12:06:50.041 6768-6768/myapplication.game D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
I/Ads: Updating ad debug logging enablement.
D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("94DF0193F80DB5F14BFF0EA958D02BC9") to get test ads on this device.
2019-12-13 12:06:50.248 6768-6768/myapplication.game I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:21001
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 21001
W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712905/7746134

Comment: @SaurabhThorat
Couldn't ads be sent because my account is new even though I opened it a week ago?

Comment: AdMob documentation says that code is for no ads being returned because of lack of inventory, in spite of the request being successful. I don't think it has to do with your account age.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat
so if its dont about the account age,
what i need to do to fix the error?

Comment: It could be because of your new account. It may take some time for ads to show up.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat
thanks you very much my friend

Answer (score 1):

AdMob doesn't allow publishers to load and show real ads while developing. You have to **test your ad implementation with test ads** either **using test ad unit ids or adding your device as a test device**. Just don't worry about not loading ads, AdMob doesn't show any ads if your app isn't available on play store. After publishing to the play store AdMob automatically verify your app and start ad serving which sometime takes time.

```
List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE231"); // Put test device ID here
RequestConfiguration configuration =
    new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

You can get this **test device id from logs**.

Or

Have a look at this article to know more about **alternative ways to add test device** in admob.
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Comment: there is  no such method addTestDevice