# Admob ads don't show in live deploy in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob, ads

When using Admob ads in debug mode or even release mode it worked fine, but after archiving the android app I launched it and the ads no longer work.
I tried to see what was the error, I encountered error code 3!! But it has just worked fine in release mode so it's not because of lack of inventory.

Comment: Error 3 is a lack of inventory, you should review ALL the answers related to that, i.e. start here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3

Comment: @SushiHangover and that's the problem, how can it be a lack of inventory when it worked in release mode before archiving???!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

Comment: @Prateek thnx but no, I think it may be a bug since the ads are shown in both debug and release mode So it's not a problem of a lack of inventory! It shouldn't show an error code 3; That may be a bug then??!

Comment: I don't know, if you think it's a bug report it to Google. They will fix it.