# Flutter firebase admob ad failed

Tags: flutter, admob

- I got verifyed Admob ac.
- I created key with keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
- I create firebase ac and connect the app, firebase approved the communication but still it gives ad error

[Ad failed to load : 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1pKX.png)

In AdvertClass

```
import 'dart:io';

class AdvertService {
  static final AdvertService _instance = AdvertService._internal();
  factory AdvertService() => _instance;
  MobileAdTargetingInfo _targetingInfo;
  final String _bannerAd = Platform.isAndroid
      ? 'ca-app-pub-6xxxxxxxxx01/xxxxxx5'
      : 'ca-app-pub-67xxxxxxxx01/2xxxxxx';

  AdvertService._internal() {
                                                      //USB cabled android, got that id with adb devices
    _targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo( testDevices: <String>["54a0a4f2"]);
  }
  showBanner() {
    print(_bannerAd);
    BannerAd banner = BannerAd(
        adUnitId: _bannerAd,
        size: AdSize.smartBanner,
        targetingInfo: _targetingInfo);

    banner
      ..load()
      ..show();
    banner.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it happen on release version ? or debug only. If it doing fine on release nothing to worry about sometime Ad failed to load which is common to happen, at least on my apps does like that quiet often but on release mode it does fine, the ads show up and nothing to worry about. Try run in on release mode and see if it show up or not, `flutter run --release`

Answer (score 0):

It's no problem, You must waiting.

`The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.`
You can read documentation: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

Comment: I didn't understand where did you see that text, restarted application and waiting for 1-2 min and still ad didn't show up

Comment: @nodermonch You can check answer for the this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3

but I had the same error in my app. I hade to waiting 2 days for display ads.

Comment: Really,but google verifyed my admob account, firebase approved the communication

Comment: Also its works with admob test bannerid and test intersitalid

Comment: Set You all in the https://apps.admob.com/v2/payments/overview?pli=1 ?

Comment: What's that mean 'Set You all in ' What should I do in payment page

Comment: You must check all tabs in admob panel for the is there any card that does not require your action - for example, setting something and answering a question?

Comment: Yes ı checked everytab it looks fine I think just I didn't add credit card but I think its not a problem for ad displaying