# Flutter admob ads not showing in real device

Tags: flutter, admob

i tried with both packages
https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob but i am getting `Ad failed to load : 3` error
any one encountered and solved problem like that

Answer (score 0):

if it's your first time in admob it can be take 3 days or you shold add internet permission to your manifest

Comment: i created new ads 2 days ago for my app which i still developing.also i have internet permission in manifest file.
The Ads working fine on simulator. but when i tried in device i getting error.

Comment: are you using test ads or real ads if you using real ads it also take time you should wait

Answer (score 0):

As an official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL)
*The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.*

you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3) .
For showing ads it may take up to 3 days.