# How do I fix 'Ad failed to load' error on Admob?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Whenever I run the app with test ads, I run into the following error-

```
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
```

I have followed the instructions from Admob closely for implementing banner and interstitial ads.

Also, I am not using a new account. My Admob is over 2 years old and I have ads working perfectly fine in another app (I implemented ads in that application only last week).

Note that I had already created the ad units for this current application a while back, and only today decided the include ads in it. Even test ads do not load and give the same error.

Anyone has any suggestions on how to get the ads to work?

Comment: your question has been answered in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3
based on my own experience with admob when you get error 3 there is nothing wrong with your code , no ad can be received form google servers

Comment: Yeah but even test ads don't show up. Is that normal?