# My Admob Ad not showing in my app getting error code 3 "no ad config" how to fix it, also my test ad is working properly

Tags: android, error-handling, admob

//This is my Activity where i want to load my ad

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;


public class TenaliRamanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private AdView mAdView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tenali_raman);
```

//AD Code Start

```
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            }
```

// I am overriding onAdFailedToLoad() method to know why my ad is not showing and getting error code
3, message "no ad config"

```
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                Toast.makeText(TenaliRamanActivity.this, " Banner AdError is "+ adError, 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.
            }
        });
```

// Interstitial code Start here

```
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4745680273727033/3318988209");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            }
```

//I also Toasted the my Inetrstitial Ad error message and getting same error code 3, message "no ad config"[my error is this][1]

```
            **@Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                Toast.makeText(TenaliRamanActivity.this, " Instertial Ad Error is"+ adError,
```

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
`enter code here`}**

```
            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
            }
        });


       // Start Application Code
        listView= findViewById(R.id.listView);

        String[] tenaliRaman= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tenaliRaman);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.row_item, R.id.rowText, tenaliRaman);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(TenaliRamanActivity.this, StoryTenaliRaman.class);
                    intent.putExtra("storyPosition", position);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }



            }
        });

    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNFvv.png
```

Comment: Answer all ready given [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3#:~:text=It%20Means%20that%20your%20code,will%20load%20the%20ads%20immediately.] This will solve your problem

Comment: But i can't find any working answer..

Comment: @kumarbittu answer is mentioned there if you are getting error 3 on admob means The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory. your code is correct ad called but no ad in inventory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed to load ad : 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3)

Comment: @DaanSeuntjens i got error from more than 15 days it shows same error...whenever i try to load my real ad

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3-with-doubleclick This answer is useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with similar issue, this error also happens intermittently with google's demo ads:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#demo_ad_units

In my case I was using the banner demo:

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
```

And after testing it multiple times it failed 50% of the time. Real ads are working since I can see the stats in admob dashboard, so this should be safe to ignore... I hope.

Answer (score 1):

First Of All go to project-level build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

instead of `google()` use this

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    name 'Google'
}
```

Did you use Testing IDs ?

Now go to your manifest file

Make sure you added the INTERNET permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And Also use test admob app id in your  `AndroidManifest.xml` also

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
```

> Test AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713

[The source for the Test Admob app ID](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

Then You can also find here the rest of [Testing ids](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

> App Open: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294
>
> Banner:   ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
>
> Interstitial:     ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
>
> Interstitial Video:   ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433
>
> Rewarded:     ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917
>
> Rewarded Interstitial:    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5354046379
>
> Native Advanced:  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110
>
> Native Advanced Video:    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1044960115

replace your ids with these test ids to be able to see your ads in testing mode

Comment: my test id is working fine it will show ad but when i put my own ad id it will not show any ad and shows error code 3, no ad config

Comment: If the ads appear and you are using the testing ids numbers, that is mean everything is fine.

As for the ads not appearing on the real ids numbers, this is because you must publish the application on the store and then download it on your device after agreeing to publish it, and the ads will appear.