# Only Banner ads loaded but not reward interstitial ads on simulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial, reward

I have implemented banner ads and reward interstitial ads in my main activity page for an Android app on Android studio. Moreover, I tend to load reward interstitial ads whenever Search function is performed five times. However, only banner ads work and loaded while all reward interstitial ads are encountering issues such as

```
Ad failed to load : 3
```

or

```
Not retrying to fetch app settings
```

I have tried all the AppUnit ID for both real ID, and test ID provided by AdMob also. Only reward interstitial ads are not able to load. But I do not have physical device to test. All the tests are done on Simulator device.

This is my main page

> MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var mAdView : AdView
private var adLoaded = false
lateinit var mAdView : AdView
private var searchCount = 0
private lateinit var rewardedInterstitialAd: RewardedInterstitialAd

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //Banner Ads
    MobileAds.initialize(this) {}

    //Load Reward Interstitial Ads
    loadRewardedInterstitialAd()

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
    val adRequestb = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequestb)

}

private fun performSearch(query: String) {
    val lowercaseQuery = query.lowercase(Locale.ROOT)

    if (lowercaseQuery.isBlank()) {
        // If the query is blank, show an empty list
        displayresult.clear()
    } else {
        // Perform the search and update the display result list
        displayresult.clear()

        results.forEach { result ->
            if (
                  //Search function
            }
        }
    }

    currentPage = 0
    updateListView()

    searchCount++
    if (searchCount % 5 == 0 && adLoaded) {
        rewardedInterstitialAd.show(this) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Rewarded Interstitial Ad was shown.")
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Search count reached but no add.")
    }
}

private fun loadRewardedInterstitialAd() {
    val adManagerAdRequest = AdManagerAdRequest.Builder().build()

    RewardedInterstitialAd.load(
        this,
        "0000000000000000000", //AdUnit ID
        adManagerAdRequest,
        object : RewardedInterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            override fun onAdLoaded(ad: RewardedInterstitialAd) {
                rewardedInterstitialAd = ad
                adLoaded = true
                Log.d(TAG, "Rewarded Interstitial Ad was loaded.")
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError: LoadAdError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Rewarded Interstitial Ad failed to load.")
            }
        }
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Failed to load ad: 3" with DoubleClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3-with-doubleclick)