# Failed to load ad: 3 - Why those links that work on iOS do not work on Android? (Google dfp)

Tags: android, ads, google-dfp

I have several links to banners to advertise Google dfp, I upload them in a similar way, but half the links give me an error with code 3.

```
Failed to load ad: 3
```

All these links work on the iOS version of the application.

In my application, only half of the total number of links work

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566485/failed-to-load-ad-3), but it's not suitable for me, because the ads are displayed on the iOS version.

How can I solve this problem?

P.S. I already checked the sizes of banners, they coincide with those that come back to me from the server

Comment: The issues comes only if that particular app is suspended from playstore. Maybe you can try changing the package name and and also with new Admob Id.There is a chance that particular admob id can also be suspended due to compliances. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610383/admob-no-fill-from-ad-server-failed-to-load-ad-3

Comment: @NileshRathod no, i'm edited questions, a certain number of links works